# Read/print the contents of a JQuery each array

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I read/print the contents of a JQuery json array.  I receive json data  from a php page example :

```
$jc = $_GET['jsoncallback'];

$users[1] = array('name' => 'Dave', 'email' => 'dave@jjjjce.be'); 
$users[2] = array('name' => 'Erik', 'email' => 'erik@jkghjk.be'); 

echo  $jc . '(' . json_encode($users)  . ')';
```

Where jsoncallback is the call back function. So far so good. But how do I print this array?

```
$.getJSON("http://test.test.test/jtest1.php?jsoncallback=?",

 function(data){

      $.each(data, function(i){

  $('#testit').html(data.name); 

      });

    });
```

What ever happens I cannot get "data.name, i.data.name" or any combination to print out all I get is undefined.  How do you print out JQuery arrays?  PLease just point me in the right direction.  It has taken ages to get the $.getJSON working - I can do it with a one dimensional array, but I just cannot get the multi-dimension array to print.  I know it is "happening" as I can `alert(i)` and I get the right keys but I cannot get at the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
$.each(data, function(i,item){ // notice the item

    $('#testit').html(item.name); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function() {
    $('#testit').html(this.name); 
});
```

or if you prefer:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    $('#testit').html(value.name); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    $('#testit').append(value.name + '<br />'); 
});
```

If you want to print all of them :-)

Also, you're expecting a callback in the php code. enter `?jsoncallback=`, not `?jsoncallback=?`